# Possibility of pangrams

Tags: language-games

It seems that pangrams, especially "perfect pangrams" are easier to make in syllabary languages than alphabet languages. The only known "perfect pangram" in English has a Welsh word in it. Is there a survey on the number of pangram sentences constructed in these languages? Is the difference in difficulty in creating pangram sentences confirmed?

By the way are there any examples of pangram sentences in Greek? Please give the examples in comments thanks.

Comment: I question the premise of this question. Logographic writing systems like Chinese make it completely impossible to construct pangrams, since it’s not feasible to create meaningful strings that long with no repeated use of basic grammatical particles and such things, and I would argue that that is also true for at least some syllabaries. Not very simple ones like Hiragana/Katakana (with less than 50 unique syllable forms); but Hangul, with 11,172 possible syllable forms, would be as impossible as Chinese, perhaps even more so.

Comment: minor point, but we typically do not talk about syllabary _languages_ or alphabet _languages_. These are descriptions of scripts, not of languages and languages can in general be written in many different scripts (even if typically they are only written in a one or two). I could write English in Devanagari, Cyrillic, Greek, Katakana, or Hebrew if I tried. Logographic scripts obviously make this much trickier but, well, Japanese managed for centuries to write using only Chinese characters so it ought to be possible to make it work for English

Answer (score 1):

Remember that syllabaries and alphabets are types of *writing systems*, not types of languages. A single language can be written in many writing systems, and a single writing system can be used for many languages.

But, it's a known linguistic fact that languages tend to have more consonant phonemes than vowel phonemes. I'm not aware of any exceptions to this rule, though I wouldn't be surprised if one or two exist. This means that alphabets tend to have fewer letters corresponding to vowels than letters corresponding to consonants. And per one common definition of "vowel", every syllable needs one. If you had a perfectly phonemic writing system, it follows that the limiting factor would be the number of vowels available.

Of course, English doesn't have a perfectly phonemic writing system. We have over a dozen vowel phonemes and only five vowel letters. But that's a quirk of our history, not of alphabets in general.

Answer (score 0):

English has "Mr. Jock, TV quiz PhD., bags few lynx." which has only English words––though it has a (common) name. In Greek, perfect pangrams are grammatically possible–-though all found so far make no sense.

Comment: What about non-perfect pangrams in Greek?